# Cannot install PostgreSQL problem with libllvm10

Tags: apt, 20.04, dependencies, postgresql

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 20. However, an errors occurs while installing. Could somebody help me please?

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-14 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-14
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So i tried to install packaged manually, but still got error

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-14
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-14 : Depends: libllvm10 (>= 1:9~svn298832-1~) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please run ```sudo apt-get install -f``` to install the dependencies!

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install -f                                                                                                                 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`
it did not help

Comment: Please remove it and follow this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart (remember to upgrade your system before install)

Comment: What should i remove? I followed the tutorial from this web...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: was 1 question not enough? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422773/how-do-you-install-libllvm10-for-ubuntu-20-04